# Functional solution for converting a string to a vector of integers in Clojure

Tags: string, eclipse, vector, clojure

I've successfully written a function that converts a space delimited string of integers to a vector of integers in Clojure but since I'm (very) new to functional languages I'm worried I'm still thinking too procedurally.

The function uses `split` to tokenize the string then iterates through the returned vector individually converting the tokens to integers before appending them to a new vector. I'm using `read-string` because the input is self provided and I'm not really concerned about safety.

```
    (defn parser [myStr]
        ;;counter
        (def i 0)
        ;;tokenizes string and returns vector of tokens
        (def buffer (clojure.string/split myStr #"\s"))
        ;;reads vector of strings as integers then appends them to a new vector x
        (def x (vector-of :int))
        (while ( < i (count buffer))
            (def x (conj x (read-string (nth buffer i)))) 
            (def i (inc i)))
        (println x))
```

My code works but I'm concerned that by changing states and iterating through the buffer vector that I'm cheating a bit and sticking to my procedural roots.

Is there a more elegant or functional way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know much about clojure, but I'm thinking `(map read-string (clojure.string/split myStr #"\s"))` might work?

Comment: split is not very good for this case since it could leave empty strings in a seq in case like this for example: "   10 20 30  " (with spaces). I would use `(map read-string (re-seq #"\d+" "10 20 30"))`

Comment: @xs0 I was concerned about using map because I wasn't sure if converting it to a vector would add extra intermediate complications.

Comment: @leetwinski I was unaware of that behavior for split thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few very notable things here:

- *Never* use `def` inside of `defn` unless you have a *very good reason* to. The use case here isn't justified. Just use `let` instead:

  ```
  (defn parser [myStr]
    (let [i 0
          buffer (clojure.string/split myStr #"\s")
          x (vector-of :int)]
       ...)
  ```

  To see what the difference is, run your function, then check what `i` holds. `def` creates globals that persist after the function exits, which leaks the state of the function and pollutes the namespace.
- You're using `read-string` to parse. Don't do that. Just use Java's `Long/parseLong`. `read-string` has `eval` behavior, which is never good to abuse.
  You can also use `clojure.edn/read-string` which can read Clojure structures and literals, but doesn't execute code.
- You're using `while` to carry out side effects when really you could use `loop` or a number of other functional methods. @xs0 is basically right. I'd write your function as:

  ```
  (defn parser [myStr]
    ; The v in mapv means it returns a vector
    ; Just map returns a lazy seq
    (mapv #(Long/parseLong %) (clojure.string/split myStr #"\s"))
  ```

  Unfortunately `Long/parseLong` needs to be wrapped in a function since Java interop methods can't be used like normal Clojure functions.

  `Long/parseLong` is only safe to use if you can guarantee that each token `split` returns is parsable. Of course, if there's no such guarantee, you'll need to do some error handling, or clean the input before trying to parse.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I didn't even know `mapv` even existed and now that I'm looking at it it's a much better solution.

Comment: @Aut0 Even without `map`, `while` should rarely be used. If you need to loop, but don't know precisely  when the looping will stop (you aren't looping over a list, but are looping until a more complicated condition is met), use `loop`. `loop` is the hammer for every looping problem. It isn't always the best or most terse solution, but it is the most general purpose, functional looping construct in the language.

Comment: as i commented above, split string with `\s` is bad, first of all because this would fail for more than one space between items. And even `\s+` would be wrong if the input has leading spaces. My advice is to use `re-seq`, or filter out empty strings from result of `(clojure.string/split ...)`

Comment: I noted how this only works if you can guarantee that the input is parsable. Honestly, I rarely ever use regexes, so I'm not familiar with Clojure's regex tools, or really even regexes in general. I'm afraid that I'd fudge the example. If you use them often, you'd probably be able to give a better example of their use.

Comment: Good answer. `read-string` could also be replaced with `clojure.edn/read-string`, which is safe (and free of interop syntax). Also, I think in Clojure `Long/parseLong` is preferred as Clojure uses `Long` for integral numbers (not `Integer`).